# Issue child component not display when click on element in parent component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm working with angular and I have a problem with routerLink.
When I clicked on tr tag of table to navigate to child component. Url still display child route but child component not display. Hope anyone help me.
This is my code:
assign.component.html file:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/abc']">go to ABC component</a>
```

assign.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AssignComponent } from './assign.component';
import { AbcComponent } from './abc/abc.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path: 'abc',
  component: AbcComponent
 }
]
@NgModule({
imports: [
  CommonModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
],
declarations: [
  AssignComponent,
  AbcComponent
 ]
})
export class AssignModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in html of parent component ? If no, So put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in html of parent component.

Thanks.

Comment: I put <router-outlet> in app.component.html file, and my menu still active, but when I set routerLink from parent component to navigate child component then it not active

Answer (score 0):

Put `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in your parent HTML file like below:-

**assign.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/abc']">go to ABC component</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is required because the route is a child route of the assign component and when you navigate to the child route, it needs a place to render, in the assign component's HTML file.

Hope, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try to write it as simple, as it is:

```
<a routerLink="/abc">go to ABC component</a>
```

and Don't forget to add  in parent component html file (mainly app.component.html). If Assign module is your parent component for abComponent then try to put   in your assign.component.html file.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks you very much